# AutoCompleteTextView doesn't show dictionary suggestions

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a custom `AutoCompleteTextView` where the user can enter text and whenever the user writes @ I show a dropdown with suggestions of custom usernames. Unfortunately, I also need to show the dictionary word suggestions above the keyboard and, for some reason, `AutoCompleteTextView` doesn't show dictionary suggestions, although it inherits from `EditText` where it does show.

So, does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it? Or should I go to a different route to obtain what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. The `AutoCompleteTextView` constructor sets the `InputType` flag `EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE`. I confirmed that this flag inhibits the normal text suggestions. The code reads:

```
    // Always turn on the auto complete input type flag, since it
    // makes no sense to use this widget without it.
    int inputType = getInputType();
    if ((inputType&EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_CLASS)
            == EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT) {
        inputType |= EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE;
        setRawInputType(inputType);
    }
```

Despite this comment, I've had preliminary success with removing the flag, as in:

```
AutoCompleteTextView t = (AutoCompleteTextView)v.findViewById(id);
t.setInputType( t.getInputType() & (~EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I recommend extend `AutocompleteTextView` class and add this line in each constructor:

```
setInputType(getInputType() & (~EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE));
```